# Changing charset of MySQL database comes to SELECT issues?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to look up data from my table, which includes varchar strings with mutations like "ö, ü, ä", so I've changed the charset to "utf8_general_ci" (because I expected, it'll work), but when I send a query to the table like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='%ü%'
```

it returns all rows in the table, even if the cell doesn't contain any 'ü'.

Why does it return every row and how can I fix it?

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` isn't a database `charset`, it's a `collation`; `charset` should be `utf8` - read [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better solution but this might help

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='%ü%' collate utf8_bin
```